# Reasonable design of using socket.io for RPC

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, rpc

I am building a web app that uses socket.io to trigger remote procedure calls that passes sessions specific data back go the client. As my app is getting bigger and getting more users, I wanted to check to see if my design is reasonable.

The server that receives websocket communications and triggers RPCs looks something like this:

```
s.on('run', function(input) {
  client.invoke(input.method, input.params, s.id, function(error, res, more) {
    s.emit('output', {
      method: input.method,
      error: error,
      response: res,
      more: more,
      id: s.id
    });
  });
});
```

However, this means that the client has to first `emit` the method invocation, *and* then listen to all method returns and pluck out its correct return value:

```
socket.on('output', function(res) {
  if (res.id === socket.sessionid) {
    if (!res.error) {
      if(res.method === 'myMethod') {
        var myResponse = res.response;
        // Do more stuff with my response
      });
    }
  }
});
```

It is starting to seem like a messy design as I add more and more functions... is there a better way to do this?

The traditional AJAX way of attaching a callback to each function would be a lot nicer, but I want to take advantage of the benefits of websockets (e.g. less overhead for rapid communications).